# Why do a FLEX GAE's logs say "Failed to run google_optimize_local_ssd script: exec: google_optimize_local_ssd: executable file not found in $PATH"?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

The GAE redeploys each time this happens. Some days it happens more than others, but today it has happened every hour

Update: it is now happening every 30 mins. This error is causing multiple new instances to run creating unnecessary billing. I can't even contact Billing Support because `This organisation isn't eligible to file tech-related support cases. To do so, we invite you to upgrade your service package.`

Region is us-1-east

Comment: This is part of the start up actions in GAE Flex. How do you know this is making new instances to be created? Do you see any termination on the instance because of this?

Comment: @Puteri I added missing logs that happen every 30 mins. It's redeploying, but my GAE console shows multiple instances (around 3) even though my `app.yaml` is configured to manual_scaling (1 instance)

Comment: The issue is not about the script, the error or the reason it's re-creating instances it's because it can't pull the image of your app. That is clearly mentioned in your last image. It also says it's because a blob can't be found. Did you delete anything in container registry or cloud storage recently?

Comment: I deleted the `container/images` folder under `us.artifacts...` bucket a while ago because it was starting to get large from all the deployments, but no amount of redeploying seems to be capable of fixing this now. I even tried switching back to `standard` and deploying with `--no-cache` and then switching back to `flex` but the error persists

Comment: `I deleted the container/images folder under us.artifacts...` -> This is the real cause of this... How are you re-deploying to flex?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all previous App Engine versions and all unused images in Container Registry under `app-engine-tmp/app/default/.../` did the trick. I don't know whether it's one or the other (or both) actions that fixed the error, but it hasn't happened again since then